# Best tool for .json file schema validation

Tags: json, webpack, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

There are probably a lot of tools/libraries to validate JSON schemas.
I have a library and want users of my library to have configuration files that match the expected API.

Using Webstorm, the IDE will tell me that my Webpack config file schema is incorrect, something like this:

[image]

The Webpack files that are responsible are here:

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/schemas/webpackOptionsSchema.json

Integration with existing IDEs like Webstorm, VSCode, Atom, ST3, etc, would be a huge plus.

I haven't figured out how to do this right...anybody know?

Comment: Looks like Webpack uses AJV - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To integrate with various IDEs, consider uploading your json schema to [JSON Schema Store](http://schemastore.org/json/).

Here is the GitHub Repo
https://github.com/SchemaStore/schemastore

This contains json schemas for many well known json files and gets integrated with Visual Studio and VS Code easily.

Also look at  step by step integrations steps for Visual Studio 
https://scottaddie.com/2016/08/02/community-driven-json-schemas-in-visual-studio-2015/